# How to group data twice in EF?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

This is my current LINQ query:

```
            var list_1 = from z in _uow.Events.FindAll()
                     group z by new
                                    {
                                        z.GroupOfEvents.Customer,
                                        z.GroupOfEvents.GroupOfGroupOfEvents.Data.Year,
                                        z.GroupOfEvents.GroupOfGroupOfEvents.Data.Month,
                                        z.GroupOfEvents.GroupOfGroupOfEvents.Data.Day
                                    }
                         into zz
                         select new
                                    {
                                        zz.Key.Customer.Id,
                                        zz.Key.Year,
                                        zz.Key.Month,
                                        zz.Key.Day,
                                        Amount = zz.Sum(a => a.Amount)
                                    };
```

I would like to get data grouped by customer id, and then by day (year-month-day). So I want to access particular "Amount" per customer per day. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Dictionary in which Key is CustomerId and value another Dictionary where Key is Day and value Amount would be fine, but how to get this kind of structure?

Answer (score 1):

So far I came with this, but I'm not sure if this is the best way?

```
            var list_a =
            from klient in _uow.Klient.FindAll()
            select
                new
                    {
                        Klient = klient,
                        Days =
                from grupaZdarzen in klient.GrupaZdarzen
                group grupaZdarzen by new
                                          {
                                              grupaZdarzen.ZestawGrupZdarzen.Data.Year,
                                              grupaZdarzen.ZestawGrupZdarzen.Data.Month,
                                              grupaZdarzen.ZestawGrupZdarzen.Data.Day
                                          }
                into grupyZdarzenByDay
                select new
                           {
                               Data = grupyZdarzenByDay.Key,
                               Total =
                    (from grupaZdarzenByDay in grupyZdarzenByDay
                     from zdarzeniaByGrupa in grupaZdarzenByDay.Zdarzenie
                     select zdarzeniaByGrupa.Ilosc).Sum()
                           }
                    };

        var list_b = list_a.ToDictionary(a => a.Klient.Id,
                                         a =>
                                         a.Days.ToDictionary(
                                             b => b.Data.Day + "/" + b.Data.Month + "/" + b.Data.Year, b => b.Total));
```

Comment: Did this work for you?  I am trying to do a similar query and would be interested if you have done any more since then.